# Rails 4 strong parameters update need restart server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

i'm working on a project for Rails4 learning purpose after some works on Ror3.
The project is build on a legacy db so when i build forms i try every field, and then I add the field to the permit method to whitelist it.

I'm having some troubles with the new strong parameters feature:

> every time I update the permit whitelist in the controller I need to
>   restart the development server

otherwise the controller check the old whitelist.

I checked that in delelopment.rb, i have the

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

In Ror3 there was no needs for this

I haven't found a solution to this, there is a workaround to avoid restart server?
thanks to all

Comment: What is your `strong_params` code? It should update automatically - I'll explain in an aswer

Answer (score 0):

**Strong Params**

As per the [strong_params documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) on the Rails API guide, all it does it use an instance method to `permit` specific members of the `params` hash to the data-level parts of your app (models etc)

It should look like this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def create
    @data = Model.new(strong_params)
end

private

def strong_params
    params.require(:primary).permit(:secondary, :etc)
end
```

I'd surmise the issue you're seeing is not to do with your strong params method, but more about how you're either accessing or using them. You should post your code, but also how you're running it

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. My code is like your. My problem is that when I add some symbols on permit (ehi I save the updated controller.rb file), and then Reload the form page in browser, clicking on Send form, the controller check the previous permit and give me an obvious Unpermitted parameters error. Only restarting webrick i can have the correct execution. I'm using rails 4.0.3

Comment: Shouldn't you be writing tests to check the params are strong?

Comment: Thanks Philip, for your advice. I've tryied with a new rails demo Post app and nothing wrong happen. I'll investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

Report after investigate:

On my app i need to make pdf with images, so on development.rb file I inserted the

```
config.threadsafe!
```

to avoid getting the hang of pdf generation process.

This statement causes the strange behavior that I asked for.

Thanks for your attention.